# Progress Bar ICS

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have an activity with a listview populated from the web.
While data is loading I would like to display a progress dialog instead of the listview.

My layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+android:id/progress_large"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I do this so that the progress bar shows itself (and this works):

```
setProgressBarVisibility(true);
```

However, once the listview is populated (with an AsyncTask), I'd like the progress bar to disappear which is not the case, it stays above the listview.

Here is what I did in the AsyncTask:

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setProgressBarVisibility(false);

        //... and some code to update UI
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this in your code,

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         //progressBar.dismiss(); //this dismisses the progressbar
              progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE)

        //... and some code to update UI
    }
```

Comment: I got this: The method dismiss() is undefined for the type ProgressBar

Comment: Then you try progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

Comment: Is there a way to make the progress bar disappeared with a fade? I already saw this on other applications. For instance, the well-known SuperSU...

Comment: @lost17 : Yes there is a way. Please make it a different question. It will help others too if you get your answer on that.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a `ProgressBar` in the layout, you can create a `ProgressDialog` in the `preExecute` method of the `AsyncTask` and dismiss the `ProgressDialog` in the `postExecute` method.

Comment: Sure, but I prefer the dialog to be incrusted into the activity not like a popup (ProgressDialog)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Declare dialog: ProgressDialog dialog ;

In onPostExecute: dialog.dismiss();

hope it helps..